# How to allow elements in any order by using xsd:sequence?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

I have an XSD with the below code:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SupplierProfileType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Subscriber" type="BIS_SubscriberType"/>
            <xsd:element name="BusinessApplicant" type="BusinessApplicantType"/>
            <xsd:element name="AddOns" type="SupplierProfile_AddOnsType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="OutputType" type="BusinessProfile_OutputType"/>
            <xsd:element name="Vendor" type="Business_VendorType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Options" type="BISOptions3_OptionsType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

I want to use `xsd:sequence` but want to accept the elements in any order. I am ok to make Java code changes for this. I am using JAXB for unmarshalling of the XML.

Tried `xsd:all`, but I don't want to change the XSD as it is used by customers.

Comment: This is a bit like asking how to add two numbers using the multiplication operator, or how to make coffee using a toasting fork.

Answer (score 2):

## Don't change the semantics of xsd:sequence

> Tried `xsd:all`, but I don't want to change the XSD as it is used by customers.

That's fundamentally wrong.  Your current XSD uses `xsd:sequence`, which explicitly constrains elements to be ordered.  If you want order to no longer be significant, then, change your XSD to say so via a change from `xsd:sequence` to `xsd:all`.  Saying one thing via your XSD (order matters) and doing something different via your code (order doesn't matter) is a very bad idea.

### Basic Responsible Versioning

Your first priority should be to maintain the existing contract expressed in the XSD.  If that's impossible, update in a way that preserves backward compatibility.  If *that's* impossible, deprecate the old interface and provide ample transition time to the incompatible interface.

Changing implementation of a published interface in any way that contradicts its associated XSD should not even be a consideration.

Comment: No way worth pursuing, but you're free to disable or disregard validation if you so desire.